# Is it permissible to wear gold to celebrate a baby boy?

Tags: halal-haram, baby, gold

I'm married and have a baby. And since he is my first kid I wish to wear gold for him but my family is opposing to wear. Can we wear gold for boy baby in Islam?

Answer (score 1):

Gold is forbidden -to wear- for males, but allowed for females.

See for example this hadith from sahih Muslim about [rings](http://sunnah.com/muslim/37/4) and the prohibition of drinking from silver or gold vesells.

Or this one on your Issue from [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/24/1).

But your son could wear silver instead of gold.

And Allah knows best!